# How to rename a directory via its sysmlink?

Tags: linux, symlink

I have this :

```
ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 abc abc 4096 2010-10-23 14:13 dir1
lrwxrwxrwx 1  abc abc  4 2010-10-23 14:13 dirln -> dir1
```

dir1 is empty

I want to rename dir1 to dir2 via dirln, like this:

```
ubuntu:~/tmp$ mv dirln/ dir2
mv: cannot move `dirln/' to `dir2': Not a directory
```

This gives error.

Can I rename a directory via its symlink ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
mv "$(readlink -f dirln)" dir2
```

Note that this breaks the symbolic link, since it will now point to the old location of the folder. So you'd have to recreate the link.

(I didn't test the `-f` option, since it doesn't exist on Mac OS X.)